# Excel macro hangs some times

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a macro in excel, sometimes the macro works the way it should but about 40% of the times it hangs the complete excel and nothing happens. I tried to step through and most of the times I found the macro hands at 3 particular statements. can some one tell me what may be the exact thing i am doing wrong or how to better to make the macro more robust and stable.

here are the codes from the macro:

```
    Sub fastcloudextractor()
    '
    ' fastcloud extractor Macro
    '
    '    defenitions

        Dim data_arr() As Variant, temp_arr() As Variant
        Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, curent_item As Long
        Dim pctCompl As Integer, err As Integer, total_items As Integer

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        err = 2
    '
    '    get data row count and load data into array
    '
        Sheets("Original").Select

        data_count = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
        data_count = data_count + 1
        Cells(data_count, 1) = 1
        Cells(data_count, 5) = 1
        data_arr = Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(data_count, 14))

    '    without Below 2 Lines the program gives a error
    '
        Sheets("sheet4").Select
        temp_arr = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(data_count, 10))



    ' ----- Begin new code -----

        k = 1
        current_item = data_arr(1, 1)

    '    Debug.Print current_item

        For j = LBound(data_arr) To UBound(data_arr)

        If data_arr(j, 1) = current_item Then

             do some thing 
        Else
             Do some thing else

        End If

        k = k + 1

    Next j

    Erase temp_arr
    Erase data_arr

    Sheets("Original").Select
    Range("A2:N2").Select
    Sheets("Unique").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Sheets("Selected").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("Compiled").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Sheets("Extracted").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("Magmi").Select

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Beep
    MsgBox "Data Conversion Completed" & vbCr & "Total no of products is .." & total_items

End Sub
```

The Macro hangs normally at

1. `data_arr = Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(data_count, 14))`

or

2. `temp_arr = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(data_count, 10))`

Can some one help me identify what I am doing wrong and how to correct it.

I am still a newbie so if corrections are mentioned kindly give code examples.

Answer (score 0):

I find `data_count = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row` very suspicious. In case there is only one row of data, your `data_count` will be equal to 1048576 and then with `data_arr = Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(data_count, 14))` you are filling this array with 10,485,760 values. That's a lot. It's better to use `data_count = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` instead.

Comment: The A1 or the first rows has heading which i won't be processing. so basically the data will be from A2. which won't be blank