# Excel VBA Variable Array

Tags: excel, vba

I have a project in which I have to extract the rows pertaining to a particular SKU and process it and save it to a new sheet.

So from the original data set of rows and columns I am choosing the rows and column and storing it in a variable array. Since various columns have various types of data ranging from integer to string to html codes.

Here is the macro I have written. Though it is working the way I expect, I feel, I am doing it the wrong way.

1. the declaration of the array
2. use of the array and
3. clearing the array before loading the new data of the next SKU

I would be glad if some one could help me with how i can go about it. cos right now I am declaring a large set of array though I know the data won't be so huge.

```
Sub fastcloudextractor()
'
' fastcloud extractor Macro
'
'    defenitions

    Dim data_arr() As Variant, temp_arr() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, curent_item As Long
    Dim pctCompl As Integer, err As Integer, total_items As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    err = 2
'
'    get data row count and load data into array
'
    Sheets("Original").Select

    data_count = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    data_count = data_count + 1
    Cells(data_count, 1) = 1
    Cells(data_count, 5) = 1
    data_arr = Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(data_count, 14))

'
'    get itemcode row count and load item codes into array
'
'    Sheets("Unique").Select
'    item_count = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
'    item_arr = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(item_count, 1))

'    It is these two lines without which the macro gives a error
'
    Sheets("sheet4").Select
    temp_arr = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(data_count, 10))

' ----- Begin new code -----

    k = 1
    current_item = data_arr(1, 1)

'    Debug.Print current_item

    For j = LBound(data_arr) To UBound(data_arr)

    If data_arr(j, 1) = current_item Then

'    copy Row values to new array

        temp_arr(k, 1) = data_arr(j, 1)
        temp_arr(k, 2) = data_arr(j, 2)
        temp_arr(k, 3) = data_arr(j, 3)
        temp_arr(k, 4) = data_arr(j, 4)
        temp_arr(k, 5) = data_arr(j, 5)
        temp_arr(k, 6) = data_arr(j, 6)
        temp_arr(k, 7) = data_arr(j, 7)
        temp_arr(k, 8) = data_arr(j, 8)
        temp_arr(k, 9) = data_arr(j, 9)
        temp_arr(k, 10) = data_arr(j, 10)

    Else


    total_items = total_items + 1
'    manipulate temp array

'    write single item data to Seelcted Sheet.

        Sheets("Selected").Select
        Range("A2").Resize(UBound(data_arr, 1), UBound(data_arr, 2)) = temp_arr

' Do some processing of the data 

' reset item array counter to first line

        k = 1

'    copy the current row to temp array

        current_item = data_arr(j, 1)

        temp_arr(k, 1) = data_arr(j, 1)
        temp_arr(k, 2) = data_arr(j, 2)
        temp_arr(k, 3) = data_arr(j, 3)
        temp_arr(k, 4) = data_arr(j, 4)
        temp_arr(k, 5) = data_arr(j, 5)
        temp_arr(k, 6) = data_arr(j, 6)
        temp_arr(k, 7) = data_arr(j, 7)
        temp_arr(k, 8) = data_arr(j, 8)
        temp_arr(k, 9) = data_arr(j, 9)
        temp_arr(k, 10) = data_arr(j, 10)

    End If

        k = k + 1

    Next j

    Erase temp_arr
    Erase data_arr

    Sheets("Original").Select
    Range("A2:N2").Select
    Sheets("Unique").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Sheets("Selected").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("Compiled").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Sheets("Extracted").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("Magmi").Select

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Beep
    MsgBox "Data Conversion Completed" & vbCr & "Total no of products is .." & total_items

End Sub
```

I am preassigning a empty rame from an empty sheet to make the array work in the below lines of the code

```
'    It is these two lines without which the macro gives a error
'
    Sheets("sheet4").Select
    temp_arr = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(data_count, 10))
```

I think the temp array should be dynamic and variable and i don't have to assign the complete data set to the array which is quiet large memory consumer

any help and assistance appreciated.

Comment: Hard for me to understand what is going on without data samples, **BUT** instead of declaring an oversized array, you could collect each element in a Collection or Dictionary object; then you would know, in advance, how large an array to create.  And if your code is working, this might be better suited to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Why i can't use the array like this : 

Dim  temp_arr() As Variant

temp_arr(k, 1) = data_arr(j, 1)
temp_arr(k, 2) = data_arr(j, 2)

Comment: What makes you think you can't?  That is how you usually declare an array.

Comment: when i do that without the lines 

Sheets("sheet4").Select
temp_arr = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(data_count, 10))

I Get Error

Comment: That is because you never size the array.  Your statement creates an empty array with no elements.  When you set it equal to a range of cells, it gets `redim`'d as a 2D array the size of the range.

Comment: Oh, and you should not be using `Select`, `Selection`. It is generally useless, and can lead to error and slower code.  Several threads in SO regarding that.

Comment: With your temp_arr issue, you could replace those lines with:  `redim temp_arr(1 to data_count, 1 to 10)` and have the same result, except the array would be empty instead of containing the values of that range.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [Excel Macro Hangs some times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45641425/excel-macro-hangs-some-times).  Why do you have two almost identical questions regarding this code?

Comment: both different issues Ron one is for the variable array and the other is for select sheet macro hanging issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151750/discussion-between-ron-rosenfeld-and-isrini).

Comment: Yes Ron ! redim works the same way as i expected. let us say if i redim a array to (1 to 20, 1 to10) if i read in 25 lines of data will the variable array expand dynamically ?

Comment: No.  That is why I suggested collecting your results in a Collection or Dictionary object.  Then you can size the array based on the size of that object; fill it; and write the results back to your worksheet (or whatever you want to do with it).